# "Испокон веков"

Tags: этимология

Интересует происхождение слова "испокон".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"покон" - начало. Испокон - с начала.
Забавно, что это слово родственно конец". Когда-то начало и конец обозначались одним словом... Кстати, и само слово "начало" родственно "концу", только на ещё более древнем, праславянском, уровне.